# What parameter would you use to invoke this function to get the specified output?

Tags: javascript

This is the given function:

```
function foo(k, m){
   m(function(){
       return k + k;
   });
}
```

What would you use for a function call that console.log-ged the result of the inner function (k+k), by using the foo function above?

Edit: To the person that edited me and downvoted, please refrain yourself. Your edit did not make sense.

Comment: I downvoted, not the editor, and I'm also voting to close. This feels like a programming "challenge", not an actual problem. If it is a problem that you are trying to solve, great. Please edit your question and show what you've tried.

Comment: Of course. But if you show your tentative solution, people are more likely to attempt to help you.

Comment: I don't want to upset you, and I'm sorry if I have. But my initial thought here was that it was a programming "challenge", not a real problem that you wanted to solve. That would be off-topic for SO. My down vote is retracted. But a suggestion for future questions: show what you've tried, not least because people may explain where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 foo(1, function(f) {
     var result = f();
     console.log(result);
     return result;
 });
```